# Fullcalendar getting out of div (ASP.NET)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net

I have calendar realized via fullcalendar plugin

Here is my JS code

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var testEvents = [

            {
                title: 'Eugene Sukhomlin',
                start: new Date(y, m, d+1, 19, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d+1, 22, 30),
                allDay: false
            },
            {
                title: 'Click Event',
                start: new Date(y, m, 28),
                end: new Date(y, m, 29),
                url: 'http://google.com/'
            }
        ];
        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next ',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultView: 'agendaWeek',
            events: testEvents,
            firstDay: 1,

    });
  });
    // $('#calendar').calendario();
</script>
```

and here is div for calendar

```
<div id="left2" style="border-style: solid; border-color: #1d69b4;border-radius: 10px;">

    <div  id="calendar"  style="height: 80%; width: 100%; clear: both;">

    </div>
</div>
```

And here is css for left div

```
   #left2 {
    float: left;
    width: 55%;
    height: 100%;

}
```

My problem that it goes out of div like here
[image]

How I can fix it?

Thank's for help.

Comment: `display:inline-block`?

Comment: You mean inline block?@madalinivascu

Comment: @ i mean applying the css on the gird div

Comment: Updated my post@madalinivascu

Comment: or a overflow:scroll, or a clearfix on the floats

Comment: `Overflow: hidden` solved problem@madalinivascu